# QuantLib-Python: Splitting the NPV of an option into intrinsic & time

Tags: python, quantlib

I am right now working throught the "cookbook" of Goutham Balaraman & Luigi Ballabio. By the way a very nice introduction into QuantLib-Python and a good starting point  :-)

In section four there is the following example that prices a simple option with Black&Scholes:

```
from QuantLib import *

today = Date(7, March, 2014)
Settings.instance().evaluationDate = today

# The Instrument
option = EuropeanOption( PlainVanillaPayoff(Option.Call, 100.0),
                         EuropeanExercise(Date(7, June, 2014)))

# The Market
u = SimpleQuote(100.0)      # set todays value of the underlying
r = SimpleQuote(0.01)       # set risk-free rate 
sigma = SimpleQuote(0.20)   # set volatility
riskFreeCurve = FlatForward(0, TARGET(), QuoteHandle(r), Actual360())
volatility = BlackConstantVol(0, TARGET(), QuoteHandle(sigma), Actual360())

# The Model
process = BlackScholesProcess( QuoteHandle(u), 
                               YieldTermStructureHandle(riskFreeCurve),
                               BlackVolTermStructureHandle(volatility))

# The Pricing Engine
engine = AnalyticEuropeanEngine(process)

# The Result
option.setPricingEngine(engine)
print( "NPV: ", option.NPV() )
```

The code spits out the NPV of the option.

In university I once learned that the value of an option could be split up into an 'intrinsic' and 'time' part. Is it possible to achive this with QouantLib-Python?

```
 NPV_intrinsic = max([ 0 , u.value() - option.getStrike() ])
```

The above does not work because 'option.getStrike()' doesn't exist :-(

Thank you very much!

Comment: I don't think you need QuantLib to compute the intrinsic value of your option. It's simple to get `max(S - K, 0)`, once you have this the time value is just the price minus the intrinsic value.

Comment: If you insist on using QuantLib for the intrinsic value, you can get it by using a duplicate of the option that you are pricing but with expiry = today.

Comment: You are right. The equation is simple. So I don't need QuntLib to compute it for me. But I need to reextract the strike from the option-object and have no idea how to achive it?

Comment: In other words: what do I have to replace the option.getStrike() in the following command?                     

NPV_intrinsic = max([ 0 , u.value() - option.getStrike() ])

Comment: Shouldn't it be possible to get the information about the methods of the option object somewhere here:  https://www.quantlib.org/reference/class_quant_lib_1_1_european_option.html

Comment: Either `option.payoff(u.value())` as Luigi explained in his answer, but because it's not available in Python, you can do `max(0 , u.value() - K)` since you know your strike K as you're the one that constructs the option after all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method you're looking for is `option.payoff()`, which returns the payoff P of the option as a function object; the intrinsic value would then be `P(u.value())`.

However, the method is available in C++ but not yet exported to Python.  I suggest you open an issue about this at https://github.com/lballabio/QuantLib-SWIG/issues so that the developers can pick it up.

Comment: The payoff-function evaluated at the price. That makes totally sense. Thanks!

Comment: Issue was added at GitHub, here:  https://github.com/lballabio/QuantLib-SWIG/issues/113